# how to use only single connection to execute multiple queries in Npgsql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, npgsql

I have created multiple connections in npgsql to execute multiple queries as shown below code.

```
    class TransactionAccess
{
    private const string connString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=1234;Database=ExpenseManagerDB";
    public static void GetTransactions()
    {
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var transactions = connection.Query<TransactionView>(@"SELECT t.transaction_id,t.account_id,a.account_name, a.type,t.note, t.amount, t.date
                                                               FROM account AS a
                                                               INNER JOIN transaction AS t ON a.account_id = t.account_id");
            transactions.Dump();
        }
    }

    public static void GetTransactionInfo(int id)
    {
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var transactionInfo = connection.Query<TransactionView>(@"SELECT a.account_name, a.type, DATE(t.date), t.amount, t.note, t.transaction_id 
                                                                  FROM transaction AS t 
                                                                  INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
                                                                  WHERE t.transaction_id = @id", new { id });
            transactionInfo.Dump();
        }
    }

    public static void MakeTransaction(Transaction transaction, Account account)
    {
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Execute(@"INSERT INTO transaction(account_id,amount,date,note)
                                         SELECT a.account_id,@amount, @date, @note
                                         FROM account AS a
                                         WHERE a.account_name=@account_name", new { transaction.Amount, transaction.Date, transaction.Note, account.Account_Name });
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to execute all queries with a single connection. How can I do that?

Comment: why do you want it ? are these methods being called at once in sequence or are totally independent ?

Comment: these methods are independent, but I want to do only with a single connection only

Comment: @kuldeep can you please answer this?

Comment: @mangalam: Obvious answer is "open connection elsewhere, pass it as a parameter to TransactionAccess methods, dispose connection outside TransactionAccess methods after use". Detailed answer depends on why do you want to do this: these methods look unrelated to each other.

Comment: @mangalam. Define Connection as an Instance variable - >  Initialize it in a constructor -> Use it in all the Methods -> Ensure you close the connection when the last method in the sequence it called. Effectively you will use one connection throughout.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks for answering, here is the total code: [link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/G4PMYvAQ). I wanted to use a single connection, to run all these queries. can you edit that code accordingly, I am so confused with this

Comment: @rajorshi: I have initialized it in the constructor, but how to use it in methods?

Comment: @mangalam , just call it in all the methods. Say the instance variable that is holding the connection object  is 'PGconnection' . Then just instead of 'connection.Query<TransactionView>... ' just replace 'connection' with 'PGconnection'.

Comment: Note that thanks to connection pooling, there's no reason to want to use a single connection for the above - the code as it is should work perfectly fine, and quite efficiently. In fact, just sharing the NpgsqlConnection instance won't do anything, since your Query method likely calls Open on them under the hood anyway, which uses connection pooling.

Comment: In other words, first make sure you know why you want to use "a single connection only".

Answer (score 4):

Why cannot you use `Batching` as mentioned in `Npgsql` documentation.

```
await using var batch = new NpgsqlBatch(conn)
{
    BatchCommands =
    {
        new("INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES ('foo')"),
        new("SELECT * FROM table")
    }
};

await using var reader = await batch.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

Source : https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html

PS : Thought of commenting first, but cannot do it because of less reputation points :D

Comment: what is `cmd` here in `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()`? you mean `batch` right?

Comment: @shashwat yeah thats what they meant - i edited.